# Replacing comma with & before the last word in string

Tags: php

Having little trouble with what should ideally be a simple thing to accomplish.

What I am trying to do is to replace `', '` before the last word with `&amp;`.

So basically if word in `$ddd` exist than need it as & DDD and if `$ddd` is empty than `& CCC`

Theoretically speaking, what i do need to acive is the following:

"AAA, BBB, CCC & DDD" when all 4 words are not empty
"AAA, BBB & CCC" when 3 are not empty and last one is
"AAA & BBB" when 2 are not empty and 2 last words are empty
"AAA" when only one is returned non empty.

Here is my script

```
    $aaa = "AAA";
    $bbb = ", BBB";
    $ccc = ", CCC";
    $ddd = ", DDD";
    $line_for = $aaa.$bbb.$ccc.$ddd;
$wordarray = explode(', ', $line_for);
if (count($wordarray) > 1 ) {
  $wordarray[count($wordarray)-1] = '&amp; '.($wordarray[count($wordarray)-1]);
  $line_for = implode(', ', $wordarray); 
}
```

Please do not judge me, since this is just an attempt to create something that I have tried to describe above.

Please help

Comment: No one here will judge you. Your question is just fine. You described what you want, what you've tried ,and where it didn't work. +1 from me.

Comment: Do the variables you get `$aaa`, `$bbb` etc. really start with a comma and a space? Or did you add those characters by yourself?

Comment: I did add them all by myself, just to give an example really

Comment: @MadaraUchiha +1? Is that not a judgment?

Comment: At the beginning of the code do you have a string, or a number of variables containing strings?

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean?

Comment: It is more than that, it is the best answer :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
function replace_last($haystack, $needle, $with) {
    $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
    if($pos !== FALSE)
    {
        $haystack = substr_replace($haystack, $with, $pos, strlen($needle));
    }
    return $haystack;
}
```

and now you can use it like that:

```
$string = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE";
$replaced = replace_last($string, ', ', ' &amp; ');
echo $replaced.'<br>';
```

Comment: "a function found on the Internet" --- that must be reeeeeeeeally sad when you're a developer and cannot write such a trivial 4 lines function and have to google for it

Comment: Isn't this my answer in form of function?

Comment: @Starx: he just "found" your code over the internet and used it, it's that simple :-)

Comment: Except that mine was first and in your answer (before the edit), if no comma it would replace the beginning of the string.

Comment: @core1024, May be that was because I was testing the code. Was your answer really first?? Anyways, I made a new function, its a simple two liner. You might like it :)

Comment: @core1024, Ha ha, Dont let that bother you. Stackoverflow is full of sadness.

Comment: @core1024, Unless I am doing something wrong, this function did not work for me at all

Comment: @AlexB the function returns the replaced string, so you have to assign it to something. Otherwise you can define it like this `function replace_last(&$haystack, $needle, $with) {` so the string itself will be altered.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take on this, using `array_pop()`:

```
$str = "A, B, C, D, E";

$components = explode(", ", $str);

if (count($components) <= 1) { //If there's only one word, and no commas or whatever.
    echo $str;
    die(); //You don't have to *die* here, just stop the rest of the following from executing.
}

$last = array_pop($components); //This will remove the last element from the array, then put it in the $last variable.

echo implode(", ", $components) . " &amp; " . $last;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression based solution:

```
$str = "A, B, C, D, E";

echo preg_replace('~,(?=[^,]+$)~', '&amp;', $str);
```

The regular expression explanation:

```
, -- a comma
(?=[^,]+$) -- followed by one or more any characters but `,` and the end of the string
```

Documentation on assertions (the positive lookahead `(?= ... )` was used in my answer): http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Comment: Can your explain a bit, I want to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
$str = "A, B, C, D, E";
$pos = strrpos($str, ","); //Calculate the last position of the ","

if($pos) $str = substr_replace ( $str , " & " , $pos , 1); //Replace it with "&"
// ^ This will check if the word is only of one word.
```

For those who like to copy function, here is one :)

```
function replace_last($haystack, $needle, $with) {
    $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
    return $pos !== false ? substr_replace($haystack, $with, $pos, strlen($needle)) : $haystack;
}
```